# Update routeparams in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, routeparams, angular-router-params

i have a route like this `dashboard/tour/2/269`, this component represents tour details, and inside that component there are some links which refer to similar tours, so when a user click one of those links i want to reload the component based on the new params like let's say this `dashboard/tour/5/150`, i tried to use a direct `[routerLink]` but it attach the new params to the old one to become like this `dashboard/tour/2/269/tour/5/150` the route become invalid.

any suggestions please.

Comment: Do you have the `<router-link></router-link>` inside your dashboard.html ?

Comment: yes that's how i navigate to `dashboard/tour/2/269`, those numbers are routeparams coming from the clicked tour in dashboard so it brings up a tour details component , i want to renavigate to that component but with new routeparams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to inject `ActivatedRoute` into your component. Your routes would have to be set like this:

```
{ path: 'person/:id/:office_id', component: PersonComponent },
```

Then subscribe to the params:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe(params => {
      const id = +params['id'];
      const office = +params['office_id'];
      console.log(`Current params are person ID ${id} and office ID ${office}`);
    });
}
```

Your routerLink would be:

```
[routerLink]="['/persons', 2, 5]"
```

Here, I have injected an instance of `ActivatedRoute` as `route` in my constructor.

You would need to obtain each of you params that you have listed on your routing for your Dashboard component. In this example, my routing is simple `persons/:id` where I would get the `id` from `http://localhost:3000/persons/1`. So if I had a router link to next person say `[routerLink]="['/persons', 2]"`, this snippet of code would update and provide me an `id` of `2`.

Based on your current illustration and question, this sounds like the solution your looking for.

**StackBlitz Solution**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-params

Comment: this is what i actually do, but my question is after you go in `http://localhost:3000/persons/1` from inside that component i want to change the param to `/persons/2` so the component of person will reload with the new params of id 2

Comment: Do you want to perform the navigation from within the component class? Also what is your route definition?

Comment: in parent component `Tours` i have a details button that goes to `[routerLink]= ['/tours/tour_id']` which is the details component, in that child component i intercept the routeparams of tour_id as your snippet above to retrieve data based on that id

inside that child component there are other set of tours that are similar to that one, and each tour have a details link but going from that details link from the child makes it look like this
`/tour/tour_id/tour_id`, just add a parameter to the current one not updating it

Comment: I see your issue. I also updated my answer. So you're route definition in your routes based on your URL is `dashboard/tour/:tour_id1/:tour_id2` and in your `[routerLink]="['/dashboard/tour', 5, 150]"` as the different segments are items in the array. Checkout this https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-params

Comment: thank you so much, so the routrlink is what needed to setup right