# Updating parameters in route Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, url-routing

I have a route with two parameters in it and Im trying to update it (just the url, forget about the content of the component, also I dont want to refresh the page or anything, just update the route) but I cant do that. My routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "levs", component: MainComponent },
{ path: "levs/:levType", component: LevDetailsComponent },
{ path: "levs/:levType/:levId", component: EntityDetailsComponent }
];
```

So when Im in  `EntityDetailsComponent` and my url is: `levs/someLev/someLevId` I have a list of other entities. When clicked, I want to update the url like this: `levs/clickedLev/clickedLevId`. I tried to do it from html with router link:

`<li [routerLink]="[type.entityType, type.entityName]">lev</li>`

or

`<li [routerLink]="['/levs', type.entityType, type.entityName]">lev</li>`

but in both cases it seems to be addding it to existing route like this: 
`levs/someLev/someLevId/levs/clickedLev/clickedLevId`
I tried from EntityDetailsComponent.ts with router:

`this.router.navigate('/levs',[this.entityType, this.entityIdentifier]);`

And also without `levs` before parameters but the result is the same.

I found this solution:
[Update routeparams in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116878/update-routeparams-in-angular-5)

but these guys, they are just adding numbers to the route, I dont want to increment my parameters but change them, their approach doesnt work for me.
Any help would be appreciated!

**SOLUTION** 
Thanks @armandyjoe for help. This worked for me, I just had to adjust passed url and use replaceURL true.

`this.router.navigate(["/dct/levs/", this.entityType, this.entityIdentifier], {
            replaceUrl: true
        });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.router.navigate(['/yoururl'], { queryParams: { type: someVariable, entity: someVariable } });
```

Hope this help!

Regards

Comment: But what 'yoururl'? the whole url?

Comment: Oh you don't want parameters. Now I've seen that you wanted to just create a full new URL like 'levs/clickedLev/clickedLevId'.

In this case you could just use:

    this.location.replaceState('levs/clickedLev/clickedLevId');

Comment: I do want to update two parameters, but I already have them in the ts file, so I just dont know how to use router to replace them. Could you provide an example? I cant figure it out, even with the `replaceUrl` property it still shows the same problem

Comment: Please checkout https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2019/4/23/How-do-I-change-the-URL-in-an-Angular-Application-without-reloading-the-Route

Comment: I solved it and added solution to the question. Thanks for help!